# Image creates correctly locally with imagemagick extension but not when deployed on server

Tags: php, imagemagick

So I am creating image with `ImageMagick` extension on laravel. And as long as I was developing locally everything looked fine images were created correctly.

But when I deployed projected on server my images doesn't create correctly. For Example this is locally:

[image]

And this on server: 
[image]

Somehow it became black any suggestions maybe?

Code:

```
$image = new \Imagick();

// I apply two colors on image for example blue and yellow
$image->newImage($width, $height, $color);

// then I apply some custom image on that one of the colors
$customImage = new \Imagick(public_path('assets/example-photos/1.png'));

$customImage->resizeImage($width, $height, 0, 0);
$image->compositeImage($customImage, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

$image->resetIterator();
$image->appendImages(true);
$image->setImageFormat('png');

// return it to frontend
return base64_encode($image->getImageBlob());
```

Comment: Hard to say, no-one can debug a picture, can they? Please provided a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson well provided some code how I append custom image. I dont know if it will help in any way

Comment: Any errors in the PHP logs on the server? Are you processing the exact same image file in each environment?

Comment: Are you sure Imagemagick and Imagick are installed equivalently and work on your server?

Comment: The usual suspect is access rights to some resource. What is the ID running the server and has it got the necessary access privs on the image.

Comment: @fmw42 well could it be problem that server uses these versions `ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64` `imagic module version 3.6.0`, and locally I use `ImageMagick 7.1.0-18 Q16 x64` `imagick module version 3.7.0`

Comment: Yes, but only if the server versions of Imagemagick and Imagick are not compatible with each other. Also the memory and disk environment limitations may be different and too small on the server. I note that 6.9.7.4 is ancient.

Comment: Is the blue part of your image? If so, then also check your /tmp directory to see if it is too full of files that should have been automatically deleted. You may have many Imagemagick files. Those should have been deleted automatically, but may not have if the command did not finish and left the file around. Or if you have too large of a file to process. How large is your image?

Comment: @fmw42 so apparently I found where was the problem. It was in this peace of code `resizeImage($width, $height, 0, 1);` I just changed blur to `1` and now it works as it should..